Does Poincaré's lemma hold for on-shell equalities?
Given a  manifold $M$, Poincaré's lemma states that every closed differential form is locally exact. That is, if $\omega$ is a $p$-form such that $d\omega=0$, then there exists (locally) a $(p-1)$-form $\alpha$, such that $\omega=d\alpha$.
I was wondering if the same result would hold for on-shell equalities. More especifically, and denoting $\approx$ equalities which hold on-shell:
$\textbf{Question}$
$\bullet$ If a differential $p$-form is closed on-shell, $d\omega\approx0$, does this imply that there exists -locally- a $(p-1)$-form such that $\omega\approx d\alpha$?
If one takes into account that $d\omega=C^a\textbf{E}_a$, it is not clear for me that it should hold that $\omega=d\alpha+C^a{}^\prime\textbf{E}_a$, where $\textbf{E}_a=0$ denotes the Equations of motion and $C^a$ are arbitrary constants.

Well, the '60s and especially the 70s laid the foundations for what is called "cohomology physics", especially the mathematical foundations of the BRST fornalism. Keywords: codifferential complex, Koszul-Tate differential.

Not in general, and if this were the case, nontrivial conservation laws would not exist.
The appropriate setting for this is the so-called Vinogradov $\mathcal C$-spectral sequence (see Krasil'shchick, Verbovetsky - Homological Methods in Equations of Mathematical Physics).
Suppose that $(N,\pi,M)$ is a fibered manifold with $\dim M=m$ and $\dim N=m+n$. We consider differential equations for sections of $\pi$. The infinite jet manifold $N_\infty:=J_\infty(\pi)$ has a natural flat connection $TN_\infty=V(\pi_\infty)\oplus \mathcal C(\pi)$ where $\mathcal C(\pi)$ is the $m$ dimensional distribution on $N_\infty$ spanned by the tangent spaces to holonomic sections of the jet bundle.
This gives rise to a filtration $\mathcal C^k\Omega_\infty(\pi)\subseteq\mathcal C^{k+1}\Omega_\infty(\pi)$ of the exterior algebra $\Omega_\infty(\pi)$ of differential forms on $N_\infty$, where $\mathcal C\Omega_\infty(\pi)\equiv\mathcal C^1\Omega_\infty(\pi)$ is the annihilator ideal of $\mathcal C(\pi)$, and $\mathcal C^k\Omega_\infty(\pi)$ is its $k$th power.
Since $\mathcal C(\pi)$ is flat, the exterior derivative is compatible with this filtration and thus produces a spectral sequence $(E^{p,q}_r(\pi),d_r)$ converging to the de Rham cohomology of $N_\infty$ (which is isomorphic to $H^\bullet(N,\mathbb R)$).
The complex $(E^{0,\bullet}_0(\pi),d_0)\cong(\Omega^\bullet_\infty(\pi)/\mathcal C\Omega^\bullet_\infty(\pi),\mathrm d)$ is called the horizontal de Rham complex of the bundle.
We have the decomposition $\Omega^k_{\infty}(\pi)\cong\bigoplus_{k=p+q}\Omega^{p,q}(\pi)$, where $\Omega^{p,q}(\pi)=(\mathcal C\Omega^1_\infty(\pi))^{\wedge p}\wedge\Omega^{q}_{\infty,H}(\pi)$ and where the latter denotes the $\pi_\infty$-horizontal forms on $N_\infty$, and this decomposition also comes with a splitting $\mathrm{d}=\delta+\overline{d}$ of the exterior derivative into vertical and horizontal components. Then $(E^{p,q}_0(\pi),d_0)\cong(\Omega^{p,q}(\pi),\overline{d})$, so the horizontal complex indeed consists of horizontal forms $(E^{0,k}_0(\pi),d_0)\cong(\Omega^{0,k}(\pi),\overline d)\cong(\Omega^k_{\infty,H}(\pi),\overline d)$ together with the horizontal exterior derivative.
Note that the double complex $(\Omega^{p,q}(\pi),\delta,\overline d)$ is often called the variational bicomplex in the literature.
It is important that the complexes $(E^{p,\bullet}_0,d_0)$ for $p>0$ are exact except at the final degree $m$, and then it follows from elementary spectral sequence arguments that $$ H^p(\Omega^\bullet_{\infty,H}(\pi),\overline d)\cong H^p(N,\mathbb R),\quad 0\le p<m. $$
Since in coordinates, elements of $\Omega^p_{\infty,H}(\pi)$ look like $p$-forms on $M$ whose coefficients are nonlinear differential operators on $(N,\pi,M)$, e.g. $$ \omega = \frac{1}{p!}\omega_{i_1...i_p}(x,u,u_{(1)},\dots,u_{(r)})\mathrm d x^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{i_p}, $$ where $u_{(k)}$ are the $k$th derivative coordinates of the fibre variables $u$, and $\overline d$ simply looks like a version of the exterior derivative that takes total, instead of ordinary derivatives of the coefficients, this result is essentially a Poincaré lemma for "locally field dependent" differential forms, i.e. if we are given a $p$-form ($0<p<m$) on $M$ whose coefficients depend differentially on smooth sections of $\pi$, and this form is closed, then locally, it has a primitive $p-1$-form that also depends differentially on sections (but locally here has to be meant with respect to $N$, rather than $M$).

But so far, we have no notion of being on-shell. On the other hand, if a differential equation $R\subseteq N_r\equiv J_r(\pi)$ is given, which is at this point defined as a subbundle of $\pi_r:N_r\rightarrow M$ with some reasonable regularity conditions, we can define its infinite prolongation $R_\infty\subseteq N_\infty$, and it inherits the Cartan distribution $\mathcal C(\pi)$, i.e. for each infinite jet $\theta\in N_\infty$ such that $\theta\in R_\infty$ as well, we have $\mathcal C_\theta(\pi)\le T_\theta R_\infty$. This means that we also inherit a filtration $\mathcal C^k\Omega(R_\infty)\subseteq \mathcal C^{k+1}\Omega(R_\infty)$ on the exterior algebra $\Omega(R_\infty)$ of the infinitely prolonged differential equation.
We thus also get a spectral sequence $(E^{p,q}_r(R),d_r)$, and the $E_0$ page of this spectral sequence has roughly the same interpretation as before, i.e. $(E^{0,\bullet}_0(R),d_0)\cong(\Omega^{\bullet}_H(R_\infty),\overline d)$ is the complex of $\pi_\infty$-horizontal differential forms on $R_\infty$.
In particular, $E^{0,m-1}_1(R)\cong H^{m-1}(E^{0,\bullet}_0(R),d_0)$ is interpreted as the vector space of all conservation laws for the differential equation $R$ in the traditional sense, as $E^{0,m-1}_1(R)$ is the class of all on-shell closed horizontal differential $m-1$-forms modulo the on-shell exact ones. If a Poincaré lemma held for the horizontal de Rham complex of $R$, then it would follow that all conservation laws are topological, but this is absolutely not the case.
The quantitative difference is that in this setting the complexes $(E^{p,\bullet}_0(R),d_0)$ (for $p>0$) are no longer exact (except at the last term), but, assuming some nice conditions on $R$ (formal integrability, finite degree of degeneracy), the so-called Vinogradov $k$-line theorem holds, which states that the terms $E^{p,q}_1(R)$ for $p>0$ and $q<m-k+1$ vanish, where $k$ signifies the degree of degeneracy for the differential equation. When $R=N$, we have $k=1$ (the preceding result), when $R$ is a normal system (in coordinates, equivalent to a Cauchy-Kovalevskaya system), then $k=2$, when the equation has a set of Noether identities with no relations between then (e.g. General Relativity, Yang--Mills theory), then $k=3$, when there are also identities between the Noether identites, then $k>3$.
When the $k$-line theorem holds, we have $H^p(\Omega^{\bullet}_H(R_\infty),\overline d)\cong H^p(R,\mathbb R)$ for $p<m-k+1$, but not for $p\ge m-k+1$, and these terms in general have nontrivial local cohomology.

To give an intuitive picture of why's that for the term $E^{0,m-1}_0(R)\cong\Omega^{m-1}_H(R)$, consider that if $\omega\in\Omega^{m-1}_{\infty,H}(\pi)$ is a conserved current (on-shell, i.e. when restricted to $R_\infty$), the conserved charge is obtained by integrating on a "cylinder-like" region $\Omega$, i.e. $$0 = \int_\Omega j_\infty(\phi)^\ast\overline{d}\omega=\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}j_\infty(\phi)^\ast\omega=\int_{\Sigma_1} j_\infty(\phi)^\ast\omega-\int_{\Sigma_0} j_\infty(\phi)^\ast\omega + \int_\mathcal{B} j_\infty(\phi)^\ast\omega, $$ where $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_0$ are the "top" and "bottom", while $\mathcal B$ is a lateral surface. One usually assumes asymptoptic conditions such that the $\mathcal B$-integral vanishes, and then we find that the charge on $\Sigma_1$ and the charge on $\Sigma_0$ coincide. Here $\phi\in\mathrm{Sol}_\Omega(R)\subseteq\Gamma_\Omega(\pi)$ is a section that solves $R$, so we are "on shell". However if we added an on-shell $\overline d$-exact term to $\omega$, we would find that the resulting boundary-of-boundary integrals cancel identically, and we would wind up with the exact same equation for charges. So on-shell exact conserved currents are trivial. This is why we can identify the cohomology vector space $E^{0,m-1}_1(R)\cong H^{m-1}(\Omega^{\bullet}_H(R_\infty),\overline d)$ with the set of all conservation laws for $R$. If we had local on-shell exactness, then we would have no nontrivial conservation laws in any topologically trivial situation. For example, a complex Klein-Gordon field on Minkowksi space would only have trivial conservation laws.
Edit:
OP has asked about a jet-free alternative formalism. To the best of my knowledge there isn't one.
The "easy" jet-free answer to the question is that there is no analogue of the Poincaré lemma for on-shell local differential forms (here "local" means that its coefficients are finite order differential operators; I don't like this terminology but a lot of people use it, especially in the physics literature). If there was, i.e. $\mathrm d\omega = 0\quad\mathrm{mod}\ R$ implied $\omega = \mathrm d\lambda\quad\mathrm{mod}\ R$ (where $R$ is the field equation), then the conserved charges would always be surface terms, which in the majority of situations would mean that the conservation law is trivial.
However similar topics are considered in Olver: Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations, which only uses jet bundles "lightly", and for the most part only local coordinate computations are done. Perhaps this book would be informative.
Further sources might be Bryant, Griffiths: Characteristic Cohomology of Differential Systems, but this isn't any less abstract or advanced than the formalism in the answer (they use iterated Grassmannian bundles for prolongation, but that's basically an alternative construction for jet spaces), or Barnich, Brandt, Henneaux: Local BRST Cohomology in the antifield formalism.

Thanks for your complete answer. Is there a more pedestrian way of approaching this subject without entering in full detail on Jet bundles? It is a topic I want to study in a future but completely out of my reach right now.

@user728261 Updated the answer.


If
$$\phi^1(x)~\approx~ 0, \quad\ldots\quad, \phi^m(x)~\approx~ 0,$$
are regular$^1$ constraints $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold $M$, one may prove that a weak version$^2$ of Poincare lemma holds in an $n$-dimensional contractable open neighborhood $U$ of the $(n\!-\!m)$-dimensional constrained manifold $\Sigma$.

However, note that the opposite direction [which in the strong case is a trivial consequence of nilpotency $\mathrm{d}^2\equiv 0$ of the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$] is no longer necessarily true in the weak case:
$$\begin{align} \omega~=~&\mathrm{d}\alpha + f^a(\phi)\eta_a~\approx~\mathrm{d}\alpha 
\cr\quad\Downarrow ~& \quad\cr 
\mathrm{d}\omega~=~&  \mathrm{d}f^a(\phi)\wedge\eta_a + f^a(\phi)\mathrm{d}\eta_a~\approx~\mathrm{d}f^a(\phi)\wedge\eta_a. \end{align}$$
2D counterexample:
$$\begin{align} \omega~=~&x\mathrm{d}y~\approx~0 \text{ weakly exact}, \qquad \phi(x)~:=~x~\approx~0, \cr\quad\Downarrow ~& \quad\cr 
\mathrm{d}\omega~=~&  \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y~\not\approx~0\text{ not weakly closed}. \end{align}$$



$^1$ The regularity condition means that one may then choose local coordinates such that
$$\phi^1(x)~=~x^1, \quad\ldots\quad, \phi^m(x)~=~x^m.$$
$^2$ Disclaimer: In this answer we assume that OP is merely considering the (horizontal) exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$ on $M$ rather than the full variational bicomplex with fiber & jet bundles, etc.

This is technically true, but it should be noted that it doesn't really cover the case OP asks about, because on the infinite prolongation of the equation the differential to be considered is the horizontal differential, not the de Rham one. The second case can't happen either, because the prolongation is stable under horizontal differentiation, so you cannot differentiate a weakly vanishing form into a weakly nonvanishing one...

... on the other hand, if we enlarge the arena to include more general functionals, not just those which depend on jets, then the relevant function spaces tend to be either Fréchet or diffeological spaces where the inverse function theorem need not hold, so I don't think one can rightfully use this argument, even though I am aware sometimes the physics literature (e.g. Henneaux/Teitelboim) ignores these subtleties and treats these function spaces as if they were finite dimensional.

@Qmechanic Thanks for your answer. Do you have any reference which discusses this weak version of Poincaré lemma?
